# How to set the version of the Kotlin compiler in a non-Android project?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I am running into a compile error when trying to compile a project with Kotlin and Compose Multiplatform, I think due to the Compose 1.1.0 compiler extension not being compatible with Kotlin 1.6.21. Even though I set my Kotlin plugin version to 1.6.10:

```
plugins {
    idea
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.1.0"
}
```

I get this error:

```
Kotlin: kotlinc-jvm 1.6.21-release-334 (JRE 15+36-1562)
Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided plugin androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
```

I can't figure out how to set the version of the Kotlin compiler that is used. From the log above the error, I can see it's using version 1.6.21-release-334, rather than some 1.6.10 version.

An alternate possible solution would be to change the version of the Compose Kotlin Compliler plugin to a more recent alpha or beta version that supports Kotlin 1.6.21, but I can't figure out how to do that either. In an Android project, you would use:

```
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0-beta03"
    }
}
```

However, I would rather solve this by setting the Kotlin compiler so I won't run into the issue again whenever the latest version of Kotlin outpaces the compatibility of the Compose Multiplatform Kotlin Compiler Plugin.

Comment: Maybe you need to install lower version of JRE?

Comment: @BigSt I forgot to mention this works fine in the same installation of IDEA when I create a fresh Compose project. But I'm trying to add Compose to an existing multi-module project.

Comment: I haven't worked with Kotlin-Multiplatform, maybe if the existing project used `kotlin 1.6.21` and there are some other setups in the project that require version `1.6.21`, therefore it still uses that version? I assume you did cleanups and gradle sync. What version of gradle do you use? maybe need to lower it?

Comment: @BigSt I finally got it to work by deleting the `.idea` directory and reopening the project. Project clean/rebuild wasn't quite enough. If you want to write this as an answer, you can have the bounty since you set me in the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main idea I was thinking about is that there are some other places in the existing project where the old version `1.6.21` was used or some other setups that require that version or maybe an old cache. So basically need to clean the project, even delete the `.idea` directory of the project, and check other places where the old version can be set. After that reopen the project, do cleanup, sync and rebuild it.